# Redirect for a single file with Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django project serving static correctly files at `/static`. I'd like to serve a single .txt file in the root though, without the `static` in the URL.

This is my Nginx section:

```
location /ms11973759.txt {
        try_files /home/myhome/nms/static/ms11973759.txt;
    }
```

I get a 404, although I can access the file via `mysite/static/ms11973759.txt`. What am I missing?

The following also does not work:

```
    location /ms11973759.txt {
        root /home/myhome/nms/static;
    }
```

Comment: Use: `root /home/myhome/nms/static;`

Comment: That's also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason [this](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/10/robots-txt/#with-a-custom-view) is the only approach that finally worked for me.

I added a new view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET

@require_GET
def ms11973759_txt(request):
    lines = [
        "my",
        "many",
        "lines",
    ]
    return HttpResponse("\n".join(lines), content_type="text/plain")
```

...and then added a

```
[...]path("ms11973759.txt", ms11973759_txt),[...]
```

to my `urls.py`.